# Не работает yiic в консоли.

Tags: xampp, cmd, php, yii, powershell

Не могу развернуть Yii приложение. В обычной консоли пишет, что PHP5 не является командой (или как - то так), в PowerShell тоже не получается. В локальной переменной прописал путь до папки с PHP (сервер XAMPP). Возможно, нужно указать путь до какого - то конкретного файла, но, не знаю до какого. Подскажите, в чём ошибка?

Comment: Ребят, ну серьёзно, что делать? :С

Comment: путь до php.exe нужно явно прописать

Comment: Попробовал. Не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возьми yiic.bat, открой блокнотом и пропиши полный путь до php.exe. Вызывай через полный путь до yiic.bat webapp и полный путь до папки

Comment: Помог Ваш ответ.
Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо указать путь к Yii.
Здесь подробно описано
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/3/how-to-setup-yiic-on-wamp-xp-vista/